# how can i get images from local folder using UIimagePicker controller

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i need is i have to display list of images as grid,for that i found UIimagePickerController. But there is tutorials for getting images from gallery and camera album for UIImagePickerController .But i need the images that are getting from a local folder containing images (means folder that is in project) and display them as grid using UIImagePickerController how can i done this. pls help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using UIimagePickerController. You have to implement your own grid-like table view.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePicker only gives you the images that `are stored in Photos`.

You `wont be getting` the images stored in `local folder in UIImagePicker`.

So you have 2 options

```
1. Save the images in Photos instead of your local folder
2. Create a grid like table view (as told by @beefon).
```

hAPPY cODING...